# django (rest) for model.all() get field from foreign key relation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Report model which has a relation to the Currency model as below:

```
class Currency(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'currency'
        verbose_name = 'currency'
        verbose_name_plural = 'currencies'

class Report(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'dsr'
```

I'd like to get all the currency codes for every report in my views.py. I've tried using reverse lookups, but they don't seem to work with 'all'

My serializer:

```
class CurrencySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Currency
        fields = '__all__'
```

and the same for the Report Serializer. My views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def rep_currencies(request):
    all_reports = models.Report.objects.all()
    report_currencies = all_reports.currency_set.all()
    data = serializers.CurrencySerializer(report_currencies, many=True).data
    return Response(data)
```

which returns 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'currency_set'.

Comment: You can query with `Currency.objects.filter(report__isnull=False)`.

Comment: Thanks - could you explain what's happening there?

Comment: You fetch all `Currency`s for which there exists at least one `Report` (so for a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, there is *no* `NULL` row).